# How to add condition in wordpress loop?

Tags: php, loop, css

I created a custom post for *About Us* section in my website. In this section, I have two message from chairman and director:

- Chairman image is in left and message on the right side.
- Director image is on the right side and message is on the left side.

[image: This would be my first loop]

[image: This would be my second loop]

Please tell me how can I write this condition in wp loop from  custom field. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need to write a conditional. This can be done by CSS.

Let's have a simple example. Assuming your post's structure is like this:

```
<div class="container-class">
    <p>
        <img src="some-path"/>
        Some text
    </p>
</div>
```

You can set a rule to float the first image to left, and the second one to right:

```
.container-class img{
    float:left
}
.container-class:nth-child(2) img{
    float:right
}
```

This can also be done by doing a conditional, but it's not necessary. However, if you insist on a conditional for the loop, you can set a value before the first loop, update it in the loop and then use the updated value in the next loop:

```
$class = 'some-class-name';
// First loop
if ( have_posts() ) {
   // Loop here
   $class = 'changed-class-name';
}

// Second loop
if ( have_posts() ) {
    // Loop here. Use the $class to add some class to your post. You 
    // can use this class to style your content.
}
```

You can even use numbers instead of strings. This is a vague question, with many solutions. Choose the one that you wish.

Comment: I think I can solve my problem by following your instruction. I realized this is a vague question but your explanation made it definite.